# jOption message not closing

Tags: java, swing, while-loop, joptionpane

Hello so apologises if this is a stupid question but i'm struggling to work out why my JoptionPane message is not closing. I'm wanting to use a nested control structure to countup the amount of calculations performed by the user.

I figure it's something to do with how i'm either counting up or how i'm testing to see if the condition has been met to dispose of the calculator frame (i'm going to a new thing that will happen but for now i'm just wanting the whole thing to close)

```
package ac.uk.valley.forth;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;



import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Calculator extends JFrame {

protected static final String operatorButton = null;
private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField textField;
private double total = 0.0;
private double actualTotal = 0.0;
private char operator;
public int counter = 0;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Calculator frame = new Calculator();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Calculator() {

    setTitle("Calculator");
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 291, 330);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.setLayout(null);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(0, 37, 275, 85);
    panel.add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    JButton button_10 = new JButton("7");
    button_10.setBounds(5, 157, 44, 23);
    button_10.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("7"));
        }
    });
    panel.add(button_10);

    JButton button_11 = new JButton("8");
    button_11.setBounds(55, 157, 44, 23);
    button_11.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("8"));
        }
    });
    panel.add(button_11);

    JButton button_12 = new JButton("9");
    button_12.setBounds(109, 157, 44, 23);
    button_12.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("9"));
        }
    });
    panel.add(button_12);

    JButton btnOff = new JButton("OFF");
    btnOff.setBounds(158, 157, 61, 23);
    btnOff.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            // setVisible(false);
            // dispose();

        }
    });
    panel.add(btnOff);

    JButton button_4 = new JButton("4");
    button_4.setBounds(5, 185, 44, 23);
    button_4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("4"));
        }
    });
    panel.add(button_4);

    JButton button_5 = new JButton("5");
    button_5.setBounds(55, 185, 44, 23);
    button_5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("5"));
        }
    });
    panel.add(button_5);

    JButton button_6 = new JButton("6");
    button_6.setBounds(109, 185, 44, 23);
    button_6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("6"));
        }
    });
    panel.add(button_6);

    JButton button = new JButton("1");
    button.setBounds(5, 213, 44, 23);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("1"));
        }
    });
    panel.add(button);

    JButton button_1 = new JButton("2");
    button_1.setBounds(55, 213, 44, 23);
    button_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("2"));
        }
    });
    panel.add(button_1);

    JButton button_2 = new JButton("3");
    button_2.setBounds(109, 213, 44, 23);
    button_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("3"));
        }
    });
    panel.add(button_2);

    JButton button_13 = new JButton("0");
    button_13.setBounds(5, 240, 44, 23);
    button_13.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("0"));

        }
    });
    panel.add(button_13);

    JButton button_14 = new JButton(".");
    button_14.setBounds(56, 241, 44, 23);
    button_14.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("."));

        }
    });
    panel.add(button_14);

    JButton btnCe_1 = new JButton("CE");
    btnCe_1.setBounds(109, 240, 53, 23);
    btnCe_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            textField.setText("");
        }
    });
    panel.add(btnCe_1);

    JButton equalsButton = new JButton("=");
    equalsButton.setBounds(166, 212, 53, 51);
    equalsButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Calculate();

        }
    });
    panel.add(equalsButton);

    final JButton subtractionButton = new JButton("-");
    subtractionButton.setBounds(221, 213, 44, 23);
    subtractionButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("-"));

            String operatorText = subtractionButton.getText();
            getOperator(operatorText);

        }
    });
    panel.add(subtractionButton);

    final JButton moduloButton = new JButton("%");
    moduloButton.setBounds(221, 157, 44, 23);
    moduloButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("%"));
            String operatorText = moduloButton.getText();
            getOperator(operatorText);

        }
    });
    panel.add(moduloButton);

    final JButton multiplicationButton = new JButton("*");
    multiplicationButton.setBounds(167, 185, 44, 23);
    multiplicationButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("*"));

            String operatorText = multiplicationButton.getText();
            getOperator(operatorText);

        }
    });

    panel.add(multiplicationButton);

    final JButton divideButton = new JButton("/");
    divideButton.setBounds(221, 185, 44, 23);
    divideButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("/"));

            String operatorText = divideButton.getText();
            getOperator(operatorText);
        }
    });
    panel.add(divideButton);

    final JButton additionButton = new JButton("+");
    additionButton.setBounds(221, 240, 44, 23);
    additionButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String operatorText = additionButton.getText();
            getOperator(operatorText);

        }
    });
    panel.add(additionButton);
}

private void getOperator(String operatorButton) {

    operator = operatorButton.charAt(0);
    total = total + Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());
    textField.setText("");

}

public void Calculate() {

    switch (operator) {
    case '+':

        actualTotal = total + Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());

        break;

    case '-':
        actualTotal = total - Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());

        break;
    case '/':
        actualTotal = total / Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());

        break;
    case '*':
        actualTotal = total * Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());

        break;
    case '%':
        actualTotal = total % Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());

        break;

    }

    textField.setText(Double.toString(actualTotal));
    total = 0;
    counter++;
    other(counter);

}

public void other(int counter) {

    boolean onGoing = true;
    String infoMessage = Integer.toString(counter);

    do

    {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, infoMessage, "InfoBox: " + "Calculations Performed",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        JOptionPane.getRootFrame().dispose();

        if (counter > 2)

        {

            onGoing = false;
            setVisible(false);

        }
    } while (onGoing == true);

}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You've got a `while (true)` block completely stomping on the Swing event thread and preventing the JOptionPane from closing:

```
while (onGoing == true);
```

Solution: get rid of it; you don't need it, since this is an event-driven program. Instead put that code in your events (your ActionListeners).

Some asides:

- While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.
- Use arrays and ArrayLists as well as for loops to shorten most of this code making for easier coding and debugging.

Comment: thankyou for the help. What would you put into an Array? and is there anyway of still using a while loop with an if statement to control when a message appears?

Comment: @SteveMunroe: re the while loop -- **NO**. This is not event driven programming so get rid of it. Re the array -- I'd put in an array of JButton.

Comment: thankyou for your help i'll take on board your advice. The reason i'm using that awkward while loop is i have to include a nested control structure in the program. I figured the way i was doing it would be the easiest way. But i totally understand it is a bit of a horrible practice.

Comment: @SteveMunroe: no, just don't do it. Post the actual requirement and do something that actually helps the program not hinders it. Seriously.

Comment: @SteveMunroe: the "nested control structure" should be in your program logic, the code that does the calculator calculations, not in your GUI code.

Comment: okay fair enough. The actual requirement is i use a nested control structure, 2 event handlers (i have not done that yet) and use Java. I thought a calculator would be easy as it doesn't have to be complex.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the function `public void other(int counter)` a bit, now the `JOptionPane` and `JFrame` both are closing. The `int` variable `counter` was always `1`. So you needed to increment the value of `counter` inside the `while` loop. The `String` variable `infoMessage` was required to be inside the loop to reflect the current value of `counter`. Please have a look at the following:-

```
public void other(int counter) {
    boolean onGoing = true;     
    do{
        String infoMessage = Integer.toString(counter);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, infoMessage, "InfoBox: " + "Calculations Performed",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        JOptionPane.getRootFrame().dispose();

        if (counter >= 2){

            onGoing = false;
            this.dispose();// JFrame exits

        }
        counter ++;
    } while (onGoing == true);

}
```

Hope, it serves your purpose.

Comment: thankyou very much for the help that seems to be closer to what i need. The only issue is once the message box pops up i can't use the calculator again. I can only close the message box which in turns increments it until it reaches 2.

Comment: @SteveMunroe It is not clear to me why do you want to pop up message box at all?

Comment: I'm wanting to show how many calculations have been performed. I'm thinking that maybe it might be better if i increment it all and then when the user clicks to turn off the calculator it runs the other() function and displays a one time message.

Comment: Why are you retaining the offending while loop? This is a dangerous thing to do and again will totally mess up the Swing event thread? @SteveMunroe: no, this is not "closer to what I need". It will continue to mess up your program flow, but feel free to ignore this advice as it's your program.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned that you want to display how many calculations have been performed when user closes the `JFrame`, here is my solution:

I have removed `other(int counter)` method which used to display message dialog from inside the loop. I have added a `windowClosing` listener which displays one and only message when user clicks on `cancel` button.

Please have a look at the following:-

```
package ac.uk.valley.forth;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Calculator extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected static final String operatorButton = null;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField;
    private double total = 0.0;
    private double actualTotal = 0.0;
    private char operator;  

    private int calcCount = 0;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Calculator frame = new Calculator();
                    frame.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent windowEvent) {

                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total Calculation performed: " + frame.getCalcCount(),
                                    "Calculations Performed", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                        }
                    });
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Calculator() {

        setTitle("Calculator");
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 291, 330);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(0, 37, 275, 85);
        panel.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JButton button_10 = new JButton("7");
        button_10.setBounds(5, 157, 44, 23);
        button_10.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("7"));
            }
        });
        panel.add(button_10);

        JButton button_11 = new JButton("8");
        button_11.setBounds(55, 157, 44, 23);
        button_11.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("8"));
            }
        });
        panel.add(button_11);

        JButton button_12 = new JButton("9");
        button_12.setBounds(109, 157, 44, 23);
        button_12.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("9"));
            }
        });
        panel.add(button_12);

        JButton btnOff = new JButton("OFF");
        btnOff.setBounds(158, 157, 61, 23);
        btnOff.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                // setVisible(false);
                // dispose();

            }
        });
        panel.add(btnOff);

        JButton button_4 = new JButton("4");
        button_4.setBounds(5, 185, 44, 23);
        button_4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("4"));
            }
        });
        panel.add(button_4);

        JButton button_5 = new JButton("5");
        button_5.setBounds(55, 185, 44, 23);
        button_5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("5"));
            }
        });
        panel.add(button_5);

        JButton button_6 = new JButton("6");
        button_6.setBounds(109, 185, 44, 23);
        button_6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("6"));
            }
        });
        panel.add(button_6);

        JButton button = new JButton("1");
        button.setBounds(5, 213, 44, 23);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("1"));
            }
        });
        panel.add(button);

        JButton button_1 = new JButton("2");
        button_1.setBounds(55, 213, 44, 23);
        button_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("2"));
            }
        });
        panel.add(button_1);

        JButton button_2 = new JButton("3");
        button_2.setBounds(109, 213, 44, 23);
        button_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("3"));
            }
        });
        panel.add(button_2);

        JButton button_13 = new JButton("0");
        button_13.setBounds(5, 240, 44, 23);
        button_13.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("0"));

            }
        });
        panel.add(button_13);

        JButton button_14 = new JButton(".");
        button_14.setBounds(56, 241, 44, 23);
        button_14.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("."));

            }
        });
        panel.add(button_14);

        JButton btnCe_1 = new JButton("CE");
        btnCe_1.setBounds(109, 240, 53, 23);
        btnCe_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                textField.setText("");
            }
        });
        panel.add(btnCe_1);

        JButton equalsButton = new JButton("=");
        equalsButton.setBounds(166, 212, 53, 51);
        equalsButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                Calculate();

            }
        });
        panel.add(equalsButton);

        final JButton subtractionButton = new JButton("-");
        subtractionButton.setBounds(221, 213, 44, 23);
        subtractionButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("-"));

                String operatorText = subtractionButton.getText();
                getOperator(operatorText);

            }
        });
        panel.add(subtractionButton);

        final JButton moduloButton = new JButton("%");
        moduloButton.setBounds(221, 157, 44, 23);
        moduloButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("%"));
                String operatorText = moduloButton.getText();
                getOperator(operatorText);

            }
        });
        panel.add(moduloButton);

        final JButton multiplicationButton = new JButton("*");
        multiplicationButton.setBounds(167, 185, 44, 23);
        multiplicationButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("*"));

                String operatorText = multiplicationButton.getText();
                getOperator(operatorText);

            }
        });

        panel.add(multiplicationButton);

        final JButton divideButton = new JButton("/");
        divideButton.setBounds(221, 185, 44, 23);
        divideButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("/"));

                String operatorText = divideButton.getText();
                getOperator(operatorText);
            }
        });
        panel.add(divideButton);

        final JButton additionButton = new JButton("+");
        additionButton.setBounds(221, 240, 44, 23);
        additionButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                String operatorText = additionButton.getText();
                getOperator(operatorText);

            }
        });
        panel.add(additionButton);
    }

    private void getOperator(String operatorButton) {

        operator = operatorButton.charAt(0);
        total = total + Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());
        textField.setText("");

    }

    public void Calculate() {

        switch (operator) {
        case '+':

            actualTotal = total + Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());

            break;

        case '-':
            actualTotal = total - Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());

            break;
        case '/':
            actualTotal = total / Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());

            break;
        case '*':
            actualTotal = total * Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());

            break;
        case '%':
            actualTotal = total % Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());

            break;

        }

        textField.setText(Double.toString(actualTotal));
        total = 0;
        calcCount++;
    }

    public int getCalcCount() {
        return calcCount;
    }
}
```

Please tell me whether it solves your problem or not.